# Connecting NFC to the Web Application

Tags: java, php, database, nfc

Is it possible to connect NFC reader/writer to a web application directly? Or do I need to have a middleware?

I mean, I have to fetch data from NFC reader/writer using a desktop application then send it to the database and my web application will then process the data.

I need to output some data from NFC in my web application and if possible I don't need to create another application for the desktop.

Comment: I doubt it.  Most NFC readers that I can find use special protocols that require a specific API not present in a web browser. (If you can find one that emulates a keyboard so it can "type" into your browser window, you might have a better chance, but I kind-of doubt that that's actually going to work in practice.)

Comment: If that so, can you recommend me anything like the best desktop programming language for NFC (with great NFC support or API) so that I can store its data in a remote database and fetch it using my web application. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to find APIs for all major languages.

Answer (score 0):

There is the upcoming [Web NFC API](http://www.w3.org/TR/nfc/) to access client-side NFC hardware, but this API is still in draft status and I'm not sure about its availability in current web browsers.

Other than that, you would need some form of middleware running on the client PC. Such a middleware could be a browser plugin, a Java applet embedded into your web page or a stand-alone application. If the NFC reader is PC/SC compliant, a Java applet embedded into the web page could easily access the NFC reader using the Java SmartcardIO API.